# How to centrally align text in HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was making a small JavaScript game when I ran into this small issue: The text is not centrally aligned.
A simple example:

```
var txt="Lorem Ipsum";
context.fillText(txt,100,100);
```

Now the problem is that the beginning of the text is at the point 100,100. So later when I change the value of txt into a longer sentence, it is still drawn staring from 100,100 , reducing the aesthetic appeal of the program.

My question is, is there a way to draw text in such a way that the coordinates given mark the center of the text and not the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use textAlign:

```
context.textAlign = "center";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `measureText()` method of the context, to get the width of the text, and then make adjustments based on it. So let's suppose that you want to put it in the center of the canvas, then

```
(canvas.width / 2) - (ctx.measureText(txt).width / 2)
```

gives the position where the text should go. In the vertical case:

```
(canvas.height / 2) - (ctx.measureText(txt).height / 2)
```

Where `canvas` is the HTML5 Canvas itself, and `ctx` is the 2DContext object:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```